# Method for linking nodes in time order

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an existing graph in Neo4j. I stored the event datetime in APOC in the node. I want to create relationships between nodes in time order.
(First event)--(second event)--(third event) etc.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can match on the nodes, order them by the event datetime, collect them, then use `apoc.nodes.link()` to create the desired relationships between them.